# Set logged-in USER in a Form requiring Current User Credentials

Tags: python, django

Currently, I can set the the `current_user` in the `views.py` for a form, which requires the `user` object to validate the post (and its origin).

Is there a better way to more eloquently set the user in a form than what I've posted below? Note, this is in `views.py` and I have no altered `forms` or `models` to tackle this aspect.

```
def index(request):
    article = Article.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST)
        # This segment below is the focal point of my question:
        if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated:
            form_object = form.save(commit=False)
            form_object.author = request.user
            form_object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('to somewhere over the rainbow')
    else:
        # stuff
```

The code works. It just seems gimmicky to use a non-committed form, store it in a variable, alter the form object, then ultimately save it.

Comment: Well, the _right_ way to deal with this would be the have a `Form` which you can then prepopulate with the data you need

Comment: Ah, understood. I'll edit `ArticleForm` in this example to do that.